# Convert date string to insert in mysql date format

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a bunch of txt files that contains a lot of data, including a date in format

```
dd-mm-YYYY
```

for example this date

```
15-03-2014
```

Researching around here i found a way to convert this date to insert in database in the correct date format `YYY-mm-dd`

the query is

```
STR_TO_DATE('$array[12]', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

But i'm having weird results like

```
2019-07-20
```

How can i correctly insert them to database any tips of what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter should be in the format your date is stores, not the format you're looking for which is always `YYYY-MM-DD`. So:

```
STR_TO_DATE('$array[12]', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

should be:

```
STR_TO_DATE('$array[12]', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: Yes i still need 3 minutes hahah